# ng-change sends different values on chosen select

Tags: html, angularjs

Dears, I am using a chosen select drop down list in select tag, and I added an ng-change tag to bind it to a function. Also I made a console.log to monitor the sent key. I found that when page load and select one item from the list it works good and sends the correct key. BUT when I select the same item it sends the key of the next item in the list. any help how to fix it

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">

    <select ng-change="GetUsersList(j)" data-placeholder="Choose a Job" 
            ng-model="j" id="chosenValueID" class="chosen-select" 
            tabindex="1"
            ng-options="j.JobKey as j.JobDesc for j in jobs">
    </select>

    <!--<select ng-change="GetUsersList(job)" data-placeholder="Choose a Job" ng-model="job" id="chosenValueID" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
        <option  ng-repeat="j in jobs track by $index" value="{{j.JobKey}}">{{j.JobDesc}}</option>
    </select>-->

</div>
```

Angularjs

```
 $scope.GetUsersList = function (job) {
        //var jobkey1 = $("#chosenValueID").chosen().val();
        //$scope.jobkey2 = jobkey1.substring(7);
        console.log(job);
        $scope.ShowLoading('slow');
        FieldsSecuritySrv.GetUsersList("FieldsSecurity/GetUsersList?hospid=" + $scope.hospitalid + '&jobkey=' + job).then(function (response) {
            $scope.UsersList = (response.data);

            GetFieldsList();
            GetCategriesList();
            GetPatientSheets();

            $scope.HideLoading('slow');
        })
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post your variable "j"

Answer (score 0):

your j variable in HTML is somehow messy, it is indexed for ng-repeat and used as ng-modal as well, so $scope.j is also created :(

```
<select ng-change="GetUsersList()" data-placeholder="Choose a Job" ng-model="selectedJob" id="chosenValueID" class="chosen-select"
        tabindex="1" ng-options="j.JobDesc for j in jobs"></select>
```

In angular:

```
//initialize the way u like
$scope.selectedJob = $scope.Jobs[0];

$scope.GetUsersList = function () {
        //var jobkey1 = $("#chosenValueID").chosen().val();
        //$scope.jobkey2 = jobkey1.substring(7);
        console.log($scope.selectedJob.jobKey);
        $scope.ShowLoading('slow');
        FieldsSecuritySrv.GetUsersList("FieldsSecurity/GetUsersList?hospid=" + $scope.hospitalid + '&jobkey=' + $scope.selectedJob.jobKey).then(function (response) {
            $scope.UsersList = (response.data);

            GetFieldsList();
            GetCategriesList();
            GetPatientSheets();

            $scope.HideLoading('slow');
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, kindly where should i initialize

Comment: as soon as you initialise $scope.Jobs, in the controller, required if u need some initial job selected.

Comment: sorry but nothing is changed, the first select of any item it is sent correctly , but if i select the same item again it sends the next key of the next item in the list, any help

Comment: assuming Jobs is an array of object ng-options="j.JobKey for j in jobs" or ng-options="j.JobDes for j in jobs" depending on what u want to see in the UI, will edit answer

Comment: And suppose in the method GetUsersList, if you are changing $scope.jobs/$scope.selectedJob, these will change in your select field as well

Comment: now the default item selected in the list shows the first item , when change the selection the key is undefined , any idea, thanks

Comment: what is $scope.selectedJob value logged?

Comment: {JobKey: 872, JobDesc: "BILLING", $$hashKey: "object:4"}
$$hashKey: "object:4"
JobDesc: "BILLING"
JobKey: 872
__proto__: Object

Comment: still the first selection is correct and sends the correct key  , but the second selection sends the next item key in the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195508/discussion-between-hassanzi-and-suryapratap-singh).

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you can bind jobs but can try ...

```js
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
      $scope.count = 0;
      $scope.jobs=[
                    {JobKey : "1", JobDesc : "IT"},
                    {JobKey : "2", JobDesc : "Sales"},
                    {JobKey : "3", JobDesc : "Marketing"}
                  ];
           
      $scope.GetUsersList = function(job){
        alert(job);
      }
    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    
      <select ng-change="GetUsersList(j)" data-placeholder="Choose a Job" ng-model="j"  id="chosenValueID" class="chosen-select" tabindex="1" ng-options="j.JobKey as j.JobDesc for j in jobs"> </select>
        
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i copied and paste the code but i still have the problem, the first alert shows the correct key , the second alert shows the next item key

Comment: Yes first key =1, second key =2 and third key = 3

Comment: if you need same at second time then u need to update $scope.selectedJob = $scope.Jobs[jobkey]; and fetch data from $scope.selectedJob.

Comment: In $scope.GetUsersList = function(job){   $scope.selectedJob=job;} set selectedJob and then you can use  $scope.selectedJob as per need.